# Get recent insert record id for update statement in ASP.NET with SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In my code first, I insert a record for a SQL table. then I want to update the same table after checking an API response. For that, I want to get the inserted record id and pass it to the update statement. I didn't find a way to get the id. Please give a solution for that. Thank you

```
using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
{
    sqlcon.Open();
    string query = "INSERT INTO GOU VALUES(@OldPassword,@DateTime,@NewPassword,@IsSuccess,@IsActive)";
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldPassword", "oldPassword");
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", DateTime.Now);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPassword", "");
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsSuccess", 0);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", 0);
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();                                

}
bool Apirespone = getResponse();
if (Apirespone == true)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        string query = "UPDATE GOU SET IsSuccess = @IsSuccess,IsActive = @IsActive where Id = @id";
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsSuccess", 1);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", 1);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ????);//get recent added record id
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: I want to get the inserted record id and pass it to the update statement

Comment: [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Note that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` only works in the same batch. Do not use `SELECT MAX(id)` or `@@IDENTITY`. Also you should specify the columns you are inserting into

Answer (score 1):

You can use "SCOPE_IDENTITY()" for get the last inserted or updated unique tables id

```
 using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
 {
     sqlcon.Open();
     string query = @"
INSERT INTO GOU VALUES(@OldPassword,@DateTime,@NewPassword,@IsSuccess,@IsActive);
select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id;
";
     SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
     sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldPassword", "oldPassword");
     sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", DateTime.Now);
     sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPassword", "");
     sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsSuccess", 0);
     sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", 0);
     int id = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

-- Consider below example with sample table.

```
CREATE TABLE #myTemp(identity_column INT IDENTITY(1,1), myColumn CHAR(10));
```

--Use this SQL in C# inline query.

```
    INSERT #myTemp(myColumn) 
OUTPUT inserted.identity_column as id
VALUES('test');
```

--You can read output sql in to variable and use it as you expected.